# Flutter native android transitive dependencies conflict (Duplicate class)

Tags: flutter, gradle, flutter-dependencies, flutter-android

projects pubspec.yaml

```
name: talebs
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: "none"

version: 11.3.1+11.3.1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  animations: ^2.0.1
  appsflyer_sdk: ^6.4.0
  auto_size_text: ^3.0.0-nullsafety.0
  bloc: ^7.2.0
  bubble: ^1.2.1
  cached_network_image: ^3.1.0
  carousel_slider: ^4.0.0
  chewie: ^1.2.2
  common_bloc: ^4.2.0
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.3
  dio: ^4.0.0
  division: ^0.9.0
  equatable: ^2.0.3
  faker: ^2.0.0
  file_picker: ^4.1.1
  firebase_analytics: ^8.3.2
  firebase_core: ^1.6.0
  firebase_remote_config: ^0.11.0
  flash: ^2.0.2
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_bloc: ^7.3.0
  flutter_cache_manager: ^3.1.2
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_rating_bar: ^4.0.0
  flutter_screenutil: ^5.0.0+2
  flutter_sim_country_code: ^0.1.1
  flutter_svg: ^0.22.0
  geolocator: ^7.6.2
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.0.10
  hive_flutter: ^1.1.0
  hydrated_bloc: ^7.1.0
  image_cropper: ^1.4.1
  image_picker: ^0.8.4+2
  intl: ^0.17.0
  introduction_screen: ^2.1.0
  json_annotation: ^4.1.0
  loading_overlay: ^0.3.0
  location: ^4.3.0
  m7utils: ^0.1.5
  multi_select_flutter: ^4.0.0
  onesignal_flutter: ^3.2.3
  open_file: ^3.2.1
  package_info: ^2.0.2
  path: ^1.8.0
  path_provider: ^2.0.5
  percent_indicator: ^3.0.1
  photo_view: ^0.12.0
  pin_code_fields: ^7.3.0
  pretty_dio_logger: ^1.1.1
  provider: ^6.0.1
  replay_bloc: ^0.1.0
  rive: ^0.7.28
  share: ^2.0.4
  showcaseview: ^1.1.1
  simple_animations: ^4.0.0
  supercharged: ^2.1.1
  syncfusion_flutter_sliders: ^19.2.62
  tinycolor2: ^2.0.0
  uni_links: ^0.5.1
  url_launcher: ^6.0.12
  validators: ^3.0.0
  video_compress: ^3.1.0
  video_player: ^2.2.6
  zoom: ^1.0.3+1

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner:
  freezed:
  hive_generator:
  injectable_generator:
  json_serializable:
  lint:

dependency_overrides:
  provider: ^6.0.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

output of

```
flutter run
```

```
The plugin `onesignal_flutter` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if this plugin supports the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing it since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs.
If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding: https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.
Launching lib/main.dart on M2006C3LG in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Note: /Users/abdulrahman/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/appsflyer_sdk-6.4.0/android/src/main/java/com/appsflyer/appsflyersdk/AppsflyerSdkPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/abdulrahman/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/appsflyer_sdk-6.4.0/android/src/main/java/com/appsflyer/appsflyersdk/AppsflyerSdkPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

Note: /Users/abdulrahman/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.6.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/abdulrahman/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_analytics-8.3.2/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebaseanalytics/FirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/abdulrahman/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_analytics-8.3.2/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebaseanalytics/FirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

Note: /Users/abdulrahman/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_remote_config-0.11.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/firebaseremoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfigPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/abdulrahman/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_sim_country_code-0.1.1/android/src/main/java/com/example/flutter_sim_country_code/FlutterSimCountryCodePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/abdulrahman/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps_flutter-2.0.10/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/googlemaps/Convert.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/abdulrahman/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps_flutter-2.0.10/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/googlemaps/TileProviderController.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/abdulrahman/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.8.4+2/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/imagepicker/ImagePickerDelegate.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: /Users/abdulrahman/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/uni_links-0.5.1/android/src/main/java/name/avioli/unilinks/UniLinksPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/abdulrahman/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/zoom-1.0.3+1/android/src/main/java/com/webcare/zoom/ZoomPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.package-info found in modules jetified-exoplayer-common-2.14.1-runtime (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-common:2.14.1) and jetified-exoplayer-ui-2.12.3-runtime (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.12.3)

     Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 39s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

I've tried to update zoom to com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.14.1 and downgrading video_player to com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-common:2.12.3 with no success

You can replicate this problem by importing only these packages (video_player and zoom)

flutter doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on macOS 11.6 20G165 darwin-x64, locale en-SA)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.61.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    ! Error: ‏iPhone ‏Abdulrahman is not connected. Xcode will continue when ‏iPhone ‏Abdulrahman is connected. (code -13)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Hi, any solutions you got for this issue?